# How to retrieve custom settings from web.config

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, web-config

I have a `web.config` with some Custom Settings in it(not in appsettings) which look like this:

```
<ldapSettings>
    <add key="server" value="xxxxxx"/>
    <add key="portNumber" value="28400"/>
    <add key="protocolVersion" value="3"/>
    <add key="secure" value="true"/>
</ldapSettings>
```

How can I use the server address for my code?

I tried following

```
dim pfad As String
pfad = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ldapSettings")
Dim blas As String
blas =pfad["server"]
```

But it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Did u define it inside `<configSections>` ?

Comment: yes <section name="ldapSettings" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the return value of `GetSection("ldapSettings")` because it does not return string:

```
Dim ldap As ldapSettings = CType(ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ldapSettings"), ldapSettings)
Dim server As String = ldapSettings.server
```

Comment: it says that ldapsettings is not defined ?

Comment: Use `Imports System.Configuration` and `Imports System.Web.Configuration` at the top.

Comment: You have to create ldapSettings section handler class for your custom section like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you will need to define a class for your custom configuration section in order to tell ASP.NET what properties it has, like so:

```
Public Class ldapSettings
    Inherits ConfigurationSection
    Private Shared LSettings As ldapSettings = TryCast(ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ldapSettings"), ldapSettings)

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Settings() As ldapSettings
        Get
            Return LSettings
        End Get
    End Property

    <ConfigurationProperty("server")>
    Public Property Server() As String
        Get
            Return Me("server")
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me("server") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <ConfigurationProperty("portNumber")>
    Public Property PortNumber() As String
        Get
            Return Me("portNumber")
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me("portNumber") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <ConfigurationProperty("protocolVersion")>
    Public Property ProtocolVersion() As String
        Get
            Return Me("protocolVersion")
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me("protocolVersion") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <ConfigurationProperty("secure")>
    Public Property Secure() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me("secure")
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            Me("secure") = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Then, you will need to change your `web.config` file slightly. The XML layout of the custom section should look like this instead:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="ldapSettings" type="Your_Assembly_Name.ldapSettings"/>
  </configSections>
  <ldapSettings
    server="xxxxxx"
    portNumber="28400"
    protocolVersion="3"
    secure="true"
  />
```

And then finally, you can get a setting using the following line:

```
Dim Secure As Boolean = ldapSettings.Settings.Secure
```

Sorry about the VB.NET, you can use this tool to convert if you need to: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Info mainly sourced from here:
http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/11/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I found out a much simpler solution

here is what i did:

```
 Private config As NameValueCollection
 config = DirectCast(ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ldapSettings"), NameValueCollection)
        Dim server As String
        server = config.[Get]("server")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("keyname")
```

usually works for me

Comment: its not in the appsettings, it's a custom setting

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1